# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Intl when try react-calendar

Tags: android, react-native, react-calendar

I try to add a calendar to react mobile app using react-cli. I installed by `yarn add react-calendar` and launched the app. Then app stops and this error comes:

```
ERROR  ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Intl
This error is located at:
    in Day (created by TileGroup)
    in div (created by Flex)
    in Flex (created by TileGroup)
    in TileGroup (created by Days)
    in Days (created by MonthView)
    in div (created by MonthView)
    in div (created by MonthView)
    in div (created by MonthView)
    in MonthView (created by Calendar)
    in div (created by Calendar)
    in div (created by Calendar)
    in Calendar (at Forecast.js:58)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at Forecast.js:54)
    in Forecast (at App.js:15)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at App.js:13)
    in App (at renderApplication.js:50)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:92)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:119)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:43)
    in weatherappmobil(RootComponent) (at renderApplication.js:60)
```

`Package.json` dependencies are as follows:

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-calendar": "^3.7.0",
    "react-native": "0.68.2"
  },
    "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.18.6",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^28.1.1",
    "eslint": "^8.18.0",
    "jest": "^28.1.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.71.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you use `yarn` or `npm`?

Comment: @Cracker I used yarn, only started project by npx react-native init command

Answer (score 0):

1. Close the IDE, stop the project, and basically close every app that you don't need right now on your computer (browser, Spotify, whatever).
2. Open terminal. Do the following:

```bash
$ cd # into the directory of your project where
     # package.json is located
# Now we remove node_modules, because it's a reversible operation
$ rm -rf node_modules
# Now we remove yarn.lock and package-lock.json.
# this step is not reversible
$ rm yarn.lock package-lock.json
# Now we reinstall all the dependencies
$ yarn
```

3. Start development and using your computer however you want.

Doing this occasionally solves a lot of problems, to be honest. You should remember this procedure because I do this a lot of times.